# Literal does not match format string when adding where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "node4"."Test_View" ("APP_ID", "DayDifference") AS  
SELECT BM.APP_ID, BM.DayDifference 
FROM (      SELECT  APPS.APP_ID,
                    to_date(to_char(APPS.date_to_subtract, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) 
                    - to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) AS DayDifference      
            FROM node4.applications APPS        
) BM
WHERE BM.DayDifference = 16;
```

I'm subtracting two dates and narrowing down my view based on that, and I want the difference in days so I use to_char. However, adding the WHERE clause at the end throws me a "literal does not match format string" error when I try to extract data in my program. Initially I didn't have the inner select in the view, but I thought doing so would solve my problem. If I remove the WHERE clause, everything is fine. I've also tried doing the subtraction itself in the WHERE clause, but get the same error. (date_to_subtract is a timestamp.) If anyone could give me any insight as I'm stumped. Thanks.

Comment: Without the `where` clause, does it just work when you get the first page of results - in other words, does it still error if you try to retrieve everything? It's likely it just isn't getting to the row that causes a problem. What is your NLS_DATE_FORMAT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This most likely has nothing to do with the `WHERE` clause. Notice how you are getting the date:

```
to_date(to_char(APPS.date_to_subtract, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

You first convert the date to a string, and then you try to parse the string. However, you don't provide a *format* to the parse method. So I believe it relies on session settings as to what the default format is, which could change from client to client. You should always provide a format whenever using [`to_date`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php):

```
to_date(to_char(APPS.date_to_subtract, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

In this case, though, you're just trying to truncate the time off the date. It's much simpler to use [`TRUNC`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) for this purpose:

```
trunc(APPS.date_to_subtract)
```

`trunc` by default sets the time portion to midnight. You may need to ensure it works as intended when considering time zones.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it is correct, and it provides an explanation

Comment: @kordirko Thanks. Sorry for being a bit harsh on yours. It's partly motivated by personal frustration with finding answers without much explanation. My experience suggests this is more common with Oracle questions than other databases, and... well, Oracle tends to be more frustrating that other DBs in the first place to me.

Comment: You're right, it had nothing to do with the WHERE clause. I didn't realize I wasn't providing a format to the parse method. Thank you for the explanation; having one does help me to understand my error immensely.

Comment: @anva No problem. If this solves your issue, please consider accepting. (It's generally expected that if your problem is solved, you'll accept the answer that gave you the solution or post and accept your own answer containing the solution.)

Answer (score -1):

Replace this expression:

```
to_date(to_char(APPS.date_to_subtract, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) 
- to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) AS DayDifference
```

with:

```
trunc( APPS.date_to_subtract ) - trunc( sysdate ) AS DayDifference
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because while it's correct, it provides no explanation.